# Bootstrap validate only if field contain value

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

Bootstrap validate only if field contain value

I would like to only use my bootstrap validator if

I got this code below that use bootstrap validator

```
<tr>
<td><b>1</b></td>
<td>
<select class="form-control" name="DaySelection1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="wed">Wed</option>
<option value="thu">Thu</option>
<option value="fri">Friday</option>
</select>
</td>

<td class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="digits1"
                required
                min="000"
                data-bv-greaterthan-inclusive="true"
                data-bv-greaterthan-message="The input must be greater than or equal to 0"

                max="999"
                data-bv-lessthan-inclusive="false"
                data-bv-lessthan-message="The input must be less than or equal to 999" />
</td>
<td class="form-group"><input type="number" data-bv-digits-message="true" class="form-control" name="big1" id="name1" size="6"></td>
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="small1" size="6"></td>
</tr>
```

I would only like to run my validate on the row that the

```
select class by the name "DaySelection" value is not ""
```

`The name of each input is goes by e.g "digits$i", "big$i", "small$i"`

where $i is a integer of

```
1 to 10
```

to identify each individual row of input type

How do I change my bootstrap code.

Because currently I got a for loop that print out the same field, those field that are not filled up also got this validation done, I only want to validate row that got DaySelection value

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
data-bv-threshold="1"
```

to solve my issue.